# NativeWindow WndProc not receiving messages

Tags: c#, handle, nativewindow

Could someone shed some light on why my `WndProc` method as implemented below isn't receiving any messages? If I put this class below in a WinForms application and pass in *that* application's handle, `WndProc` receives messages as I would expect. However, using the IntPtr returned from `GetForegroundWindow()` as I have below doesn't yield the same results. (FWIW, I have my code set up to execute `GetForegroundWindow()` when my application is hidden, so I'm certain that the IntPtr is referring to an outside application.) My goal here is to monitor certain events from outside applications.

```
public class MyNativeWindow : NativeWindow
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    public MyNativeWindow()
    {
        this.AssignHandle(GetForegroundWindow());
    }

    // Never called... I set a breakpoint
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't recieve Messages of another process.

Comment: Got any suggestions as to how I can receive messages of other processes?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to inject a dll into target process. Search for "dll injection"